# Sum with prime counting function(Resolved, but feel to answer)

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Can someone help me find an expression for the sum(or a non-trivial lower bound) $\sum_{\alpha \in P^{´} \alpha \leq N} \pi(\alpha) $ (where $P^{´}$ is the set of prime numbers greater than 2 and $\pi(i)$ is the number of primes less than $i$).

Comment: What values do you get for this expression for values of $N$ up to $12$? It should become obvious pretty quickly.

Comment: Please [update your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4050423/edit) with the results you find so that people can answer at an appropriate level.

Comment: I came up with $\frac{\pi(N)(\pi(N) +1)}{2} -1$